# Как получить доступ к методу из контруктора?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Имеется такой кусок, пытаюсь вызвать метод класса внутри конструктора, т.е. `aplyStyles`, но в консоли выбивает такую ошибку:

> ReferenceError: aplyStyles is not defined

Как поступают в таких ситуациях?

```js
'use strict';

;(function() {

 class CubePage {

  constructor() {
   

   this.cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
   this.slides = document.querySelectorAll('.cube_vertical');

   this.flipping = false;
   this.cubeDeg = 0;
   this.pageHeigt = () => {

    let height = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
      let computedStyles = getComputedStyle(this.slides[i]);
      height = height + parseInt(computedStyles.height);
     }

     return height;
   }

   
    aplyStyles(slides[0], {
     transform: "translateZ(200px)"
    })

    aplyStyles(slides[1], {
     transform: "rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px)"
    })
    

  }


  aplyStyles(elem, styles) {

    for(var key in styles) {
      elem.style[key] = styles[key];  
    }

  }

  showHeight() {
   console.log(this.pageHeigt());
   console.log(this.slides);
  }
 }

 var some = new CubePage;
 some.showHeight();


})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы класса доступны в конструкторе через ключевое слово `this`. В вашем случае `aplyStyles` можно вызвать следующим образом:

```
this.aplyStyles(this.slides[0], {
  transform: "translateZ(200px)"
})

this.aplyStyles(this.slides[1], {
  transform: "rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px)"
})
```

По сути, мы ссылаемся на текущую сущность, которая может получить эти методы из прототипа. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

P.S. У вас пропущена буква `p` в имени метода (правильно не `aplyStyles`, а `applyStyles`).